# Can't access HTMLCollection even there is element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm tring to change some element when the condition is satisfied. 
I need `xTick[0]` but it always undefined even there is HTMLColletion

```
var xTick = document.getElementsByClassName('some class name')
```

console logs

```
console.log(xTick)
output:
    HTMLCollection []
    > 0: text
    > 1: text
    > 2: text
    ...
    > 8: text
    > 9: text
      length: 10
    > __proto__: HTMLCollection


console.log(xTick.length)
output: 0


console.log(xTick[0])
output: undefined
```

`console.log(xTick)` has correct output but `console.log(xTick[0])` and `console.log(xTick.length)` dosen't

Comment: The list is updating live. Likely the element does *not* exist when you actually query for it, which `xTick.length` confirms. The element appears sometime later, and you see the object update live in the console too.

Comment: @deceze Oh, I thought element always exist. I made button and event that has ```console.log``` when I press button when element exist, I could get correct output. Thanks